# Вывод данных

Tags: color, php, html

Здравствуйте, подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы при выводе из базы комментариев цвет фона чередовался через один. Вот как выглядеть чередование должно.

```
    <li class="bg-color-red" >
    <div class="avatar"><img src="images/myface.jpg</div>
    <div class="reply">
        <div class=""><?php echo $m[date] ?></div>
        <div class=""><?php echo $m[author] ?></div>
        <div class="text"><?php echo $m[text] ?></div>
    </div>
</li>

<li class="bg-color-pink" style="width:850px; min-height:100px;">
    <div class="avatar"><img src="images/myface.jpg</div>
    <div class="reply">
        <div class="date"></div>
        <div class="author"></div>
        <div class="text"></div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Как вы видите, класс первого комментария bg-color-red, а второго bg-color-pink. Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы при выводе данных с таблицы они чередовались. Одна запись одного цвета, вторая другого, третья такого, как и первая и тд. и тп. Как сделать вот такой вот вывод данных? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Отделите стили (цвет, размер) от верстки! Ниже @KaZaца указал на псевдокласс nth-child - используйте его.

Answer (score 4):

Для двух чередующихся классов на **php**:

```
$i=0;
foreach($comments as $comment)
{
  echo "<li class='".(++$i%2?'class_for_odd':'class_for_even')."' >";
  //вывод остального
  echo "</li>";
}
```

В **css3** есть псевдокласс [nth-child](http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child):

```
 ul li:nth-child(odd) {...}
 ul li:nth-child(even) {...}
```

**jQuery** поддерживает фильтр [:nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li:nth-child(odd)').addClass('class_odd');
  $('li:nth-child(even)').addClass('class_even');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Комментарии же скорее всего будут в цикле выводиться... Так что можно завести счетчик и смотреть на его четность(естественно инкриминируя его каждую итерацию). Если он не четный то присваиваем блоку один класс если не четный то другой.

```
<?php $count = 1;
foreach($comments as $comment) //можете использовать for или while, здесь это не важно
{ ?>
    <li class="<?php if($count%2 == 0) { echo "oneClass"; } ?>">$comment->text</li>
    <li class="<?php if($count%2 != 0) { echo "anotherClass"; } ?>">$comment->text</li>
<?php $count++; } ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо!А у вас случайно нет примера ?

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Я надеюсь Вы сможете подогнать его под свой код

Comment: Код неверный. @KryDos посмотрите внимательнее. Нет инкремента, выводится два <li> вместо одного.

Comment: @KaZаца, Спасибо большое. Писал прям здесь. Код не проверил :(